# How to Interpret FCurve Keyframe Handles

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, keyframes, fcurves

I've been pulling my hair out over this concept for a couple of days now, and I can't find a satisfying answer online.

I want to take each `Keyframe` in an `FCurve` and output it to file as a Cubic Hermite curve. As far as I can tell, the `FCurve`s are (or can be) Cubic Bezier curves. That means it should be trivial to transform the `Keyframe` left/right handles and control point from Bezier to Hermite.

However, I have no idea how to interpret the meaning of the handles. They have a tuple `(time, value)`, when I would expect them to have a single value for a 1D curve. Additionally, changing both `time` *and* `value` individually affects the spline, so it seems unlikely that they are calculated into a single value under the hood.

So, my question is: what is the proper way to interpret the handles on a `Keyframe`? What do I need to do to prepare the handles for transformation into Hermite? Do I even need to do anything at all?

Comment: Actually I have no idea what Hermite curves are and this is usually not the scope of this Blender website. I only know there is not much to interpret in the meaning of the handles. I guess there are certainly somewhere out there that tell you how the angle and the length of the handle are influencing the curve. The only thing is, Blender doesn't show you the angle and length, it shows you the position of the handle's end point, with X being the frame time and Y the value. Together with coordinates of the control point the handle belongs to you can calculate the length and angle of the handle.

Comment: So, if you find a formula that tells you in which way the handle effects the Bézier curve and another formula that tells you how a Hermite curve is built, then you might be able to transfer it.

Comment: I see, I appreciate the insight. I understand the bit about Blender's StackExchange and Hermite, I was just interested in Blender's implementation of the curve handles. Thank you! I think I have an idea of where to go with this now.

Comment: I don't know how the Bézier curves are implemented in Blender - I only know what values are shown in the _Graph Editor_ which are obviously the simple X and Y coordinates of the handles' end points visible in the graph. The internal implementation is most likely totally different, this is just the resulting graphic.